# Back to homepage if value in searchbar is null Django

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

Hi i want to ask about searchbar in django, i want to create something like if there is no results to show, show all or back to homepage. And my question is how to do it ?

Here is my code:

views:

```
def SearchPage(request):
    kategorie = Kategoria.objects.all()
    srh = request.GET['query']
    kategorie_search = Kategoria.objects.filter(nazwa__icontains=srh)
    dane = {'kategorie' : kategorie, 'kategorie_search' : kategorie_search, 'search' : srh}
    return render(request, 'search_result.html', dane)
```

html:

```
        {% for kat in kategorie_search %}
            
                <div class="flex-container">
                    
                    <div class="between">
                <a href = "/episodes/{{ kat.slug }}"><img id="resize" src="{{ kat.miniaturka }}" class="imgh" title="{{ kat.nazwa }}"></a>
               
        <figcaption class="caption"><a style= "color: #ffffff" href = "/episodes/{{ kat.slug }}"> {{kat.nazwa}} </a></figcaption>



                </div>
        </div>
             
            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
def SearchPage(request):
    kategorie = Kategoria.objects.all()
    srh = request.GET['query']
    kategorie_search = Kategoria.objects.filter(nazwa__icontains=srh)
    if kategorie_search.exists():
        dane = {'kategorie' : kategorie, 'kategorie_search' : kategorie_search, 'search' : srh}
        return render(request, 'search_result.html', dane)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: I changed this a little to:
```
def SearchPage(request):
    kategorie = Kategoria.objects.all()
    srh = request.GET['query']
    kategorie_search = Kategoria.objects.filter(nazwa__icontains=srh)
    if kategorie_search.exists():
        dane = {'kategorie' : kategorie, 'kategorie_search' : kategorie_search, 'search' : srh}
        return render(request, 'search_result.html', dane)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```
And now work